# Button not registering taps

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

The button in this cell does not register taps. The print statement in `downloadEpisode()` does not print and the button isn't highlighted/change color when tapped. The table view cell however is selected when I tap the button. I thought the cell was below the button view but that's not the case (I have checked in UI view hierarchy).

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    let cell: PFTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PFTableViewCell
    if let title = object?["title"] as? String {
        cell.textLabel?.text = title
    }
    let downloadButton = UIButton(type: .RoundedRect)
    downloadButton.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.bounds.width - 100, cell.contentView.bounds.height / 2, 100, 0)
    downloadButton.setTitle("Download", forState: .Normal)
    downloadButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
    downloadButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Selected)
    downloadButton.tag = indexPath.row
    downloadButton.addTarget(self, action: "downloadEpisode:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(downloadButton)
    cell.contentView.bringSubviewToFront(downloadButton)
// using cell.addSubview(downloadButton) doesn't work either.


    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will ever help someone else but here is the solution:

```
    downloadButton.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.bounds.width - 100, cell.contentView.bounds.height / 2, 100, 0)
```

should be

```
     downloadButton.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.bounds.width - 100, cell.contentView.bounds.height / 2, 100, 40)
```

The height of the button was 0, which was intentional because the text would still display normally and I thought the touch area would be just the text, turns out it doesn't work like that.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer :) It will help others.